# Ignore SQL INNER JOIN if there are no records to join?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, inner-join

I have the following Join

```
INNER JOIN @SynonymTable AS A ON ([Products].[Title] LIKE A.[Synonym])
```

The @SynonymTable table variable contains (if needed) a list of items terms such as:

```
%shirt%
%blouse%
%petticoat%
```

These are all based on a list of a synonyms for a particular keyword search, such as the term 'shirt' - from this I can then find all items that may be related, etc.  The problem is that if the there is no keyword supplied the query obviously does not join anything.

Is there anyway to eliminate the join or return all items if there are no items in the synonym table?

I've found posts such as [Bypass last INNER JOIN in query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830619/bypass-last-inner-join-in-query) but am unable to get it to work for my scenario?

Any help or advice would be great.

Comment: I might not got the point, but why don't you use a left outer join?

Comment: then the wrong products would be returned if the table is filled in

Comment: I think @Mithrandir is right: using a LEFT JOIN it will return all the record matching a provided "Synonym" and also the not matching record with join field NULL

Comment: left join will give you all the records from products and if there is a record in synonyms it will give you info on that 2 or multiple rows.

Comment: Can you check the `@SynonymTable` before the query runs to see if there is a record, and if not, then insert `%` into it so the query will return everything?

Comment: @ufosnowcat: well, one might use distinct to supress that ...

Comment: @Mithrandir The problem in doing that is that it is then returning duplicates rows from the [Products] table.

Comment: @JamesL. I tried that earlier and for some reason it did not return anything at all.

Comment: @Mithrandir disticnt will still get you wrong results ex prod table has aa bb syn table has %a% then select distinct * from prod left join syn on prod.Title LIKE syn.Synonym will give you 2 decords 1) aa %a% and 2) bb null

Comment: You can use a LEFT JOIN in this case with <column> IS NOT NULL OR NOT EXISTS ... -> it should do exactly what you need

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use one select like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Products 
LEFT JOIN @SynonymTable AS A ON ([Products].[Title] LIKE A.[Synonym])
WHERE A.[Synonym] IS NOT NULL 
      OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT B.[Synonym] FROM @SynonymTable B)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use two different queries, check if `synonymtable` has rows and run query with `inner join` else return rows from `products` table

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @SynonymTable)
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM Products 
  INNER JOIN @SynonymTable AS A ON ([Products].[Title] LIKE A.[Synonym])
END
ELSE
  SELECT * FROM Products
```

Comment: Great answer and would have done this myself, but the join made up part of a larger query which I am unable to break up.

Comment: `IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @SynonymTable)` would be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

a solution would be to not join on the synonym table but to use it in a where clause

not the most elegant code but should work (unless you have a big synonym table then it gets slower)

```
where ((select count(1) from @SynonymTable) = 0 or 
       (select count(1) from @SynonymTable 
        where [Products].[Title] LIKE @SynonymTable.[Synonym]) > 0 ))
```